# Express application stop responding

Tags: node.js, express

I am running an app on Express framework version v3.18.3, nodejs is v0.12.0, FreeBSD server. Problem is after some time it stops responding. I can see access log is being filled with url's but response time is `-` instead of lets say 78ms. So at some point without logging any error response times disappear:

`access.log
GET /programs/224/ 200 78.628 ms - 40673
GET /programs/10/ 200 76.315 ms - 39278
GET /archive/1435/ - - ms - -
GET /archive/899/ - - ms - -
GET /archive/1647/ - - ms - -`

I thought it could be `http.get` method eating pool of 5 connections, but it seems to be not, because there is not even a single call to file that uses `http.get`.

I thought it could be `mysql` pool has unreleased connection, but I've checked every single query and all of them have `conn.release()` in callback.

I am desperate, what else could I check?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of the `/archive/...` route handler? (provided that those are causing the issue; otherwise, any handler that is causing issues and may provide a clue as to what's happening)

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons. Since you have not provided any code you can still check if any or all are true for your app.If yes avoid these

1. Check if you are using process.on('uncaughtException', ...). It can make the a node app hung.
2. Also check if the modules you are using has a debug mode enabled for any event.
3. Check if you are outputting your nodejs results to any log file ( e.g exec su nodejs node /home/nodejs/server.js | /home/nodejs/logger.js ). This would make the upstart daemon supervise the logging process instead of the server.